# java string replace a backslash double quote with a single quote

Tags: java, string, replace, escaping, quote

This is driving me mad so please help if you can...

I have a Java string and I want to replace all backslash double-quote sequences with a single-quote and even though I'm escaping what I believe is necessary the replace command does nothing to the string.

```
entry.replace("\\\"", "'");
```

Appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: did you already tried: `entry = entry.replace("\\\"", "'");` documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: What does the string look like before the attempt to replace its content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java Strings are immutable. What ever operation you perform on a String results in new object. You need to re-assign the value after operation. Following may help you.

```
entry = entry.replace("\\\"", "'");
```

Comment: Thank you thinksteep. The formal result assignment back onto the string was the fix.  Superb 5*.  :-D

Answer (score 2):

Usual mistake I always do :)

You should do this intead: `entry = entry.replace("\\\"", "'");`